# libxml2 install error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1? What are the dependencies of libxml2?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to install libxml2 on Ubuntu 9.10 and getting errors:

```
$ sudo python setup.py develop
```

Its a very lengthy error message but the last error is

> Setup script exited with error: Command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1.

Can anybody tell me why I am getting this error?

What are the dependencies or libraries required to install this?

scenario: I am trying to setup the reddit.com clone, and when I run develop command, its generating a huge error as stated above.

Comment: Post the entire error.  Truncating the error message is useless and just makes it harder for people to help.

Comment: You are getting the error because something went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem today on Centos 5.4. If you experience such an error on this system (and on RHEL and probably Fedora) you have to install libxml2-devel and/or libxslt-devel.

P.S. I know it's not an answer for this question in general however it maybe helpful for someone so I decided to write down it here.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

or the graphical equivalents?

Answer (score 0):

As Dirk says, you can install the libxml2 package with apt.

If you are building from source for some reason a good starting point is this command

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep libxml2
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the entire error:

amed ‘_extensions’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134800: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134800: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134800: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134800: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134801: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_global_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134801: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_global_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134801: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_global_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134801: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_global_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134802: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_utf_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134802: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_utf_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134802: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_utf_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134802: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_utf_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134803: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_function_cache’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134803: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_function_cache’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134803: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_function_cache’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134803: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_function_cache’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134804: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_eval_context_dict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134804: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_eval_context_dict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134804: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_eval_context_dict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134804: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_eval_context_dict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134805: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134805: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134805: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134805: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134806: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_documents’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134806: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_documents’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134806: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_documents’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134806: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_documents’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134807: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_exc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134807: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_exc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134807: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_exc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134807: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_exc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_traverse_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134814: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_doc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134815: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_doc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134817: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_extensions’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134818: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_extensions’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134820: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134821: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134823: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_global_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134824: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_global_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134826: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_utf_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134827: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_utf_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134829: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_function_cache’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134830: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_function_cache’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134832: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_eval_context_dict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134833: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_eval_context_dict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134835: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134836: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134838: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_documents’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134839: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_documents’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134841: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_exc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134842: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_exc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_clear_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134850: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_doc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134851: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_doc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134853: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_extensions’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134854: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_extensions’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134856: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134857: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134859: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_global_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134860: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_global_namespaces’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134862: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_utf_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134863: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_utf_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134865: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_function_cache’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134866: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_function_cache’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134868: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_eval_context_dict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134869: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_eval_context_dict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134871: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134872: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_refs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134874: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_documents’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134875: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_temp_documents’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134877: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_exc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134878: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__BaseContext’ has no member named ‘_exc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_new_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135462: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135463: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135478: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135478: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135478: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135478: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135479: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135479: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135479: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135479: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_traverse_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135486: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135487: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135489: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135490: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_clear_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135498: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135499: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135501: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:135502: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XPathEvaluatorBase’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_new_4lxml_5etree_XPath’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136025: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc_4lxml_5etree_XPath’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136040: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136040: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136040: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136040: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_traverse_4lxml_5etree_XPath’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136048: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136049: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_clear_4lxml_5etree_XPath’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136058: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136059: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: At top level:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136071: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XPath’ has no member named ‘path’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_new_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136388: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’ has no member named ‘_parser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136394: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’ has no member named ‘_parser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136394: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’ has no member named ‘_parser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136394: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’ has no member named ‘_parser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136394: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’ has no member named ‘_parser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_traverse_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136402: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’ has no member named ‘_parser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136403: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’ has no member named ‘_parser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_clear_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136412: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’ has no member named ‘_parser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136413: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTResolverContext’ has no member named ‘_parser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_new_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136758: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_element_proxy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136759: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_elements’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136765: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_element_proxy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136765: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_element_proxy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136765: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_element_proxy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136765: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_element_proxy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136766: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_elements’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136766: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_elements’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136766: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_elements’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136766: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_elements’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_traverse_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136774: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_element_proxy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136775: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_element_proxy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136777: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_elements’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136778: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_elements’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_clear_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136787: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_element_proxy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136788: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_element_proxy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136790: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_elements’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:136791: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree__XSLTContext’ has no member named ‘_extension_elements’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_new_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137137: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_xslt_resolver_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137138: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_access_control’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137139: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_dealloc_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137155: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_xslt_resolver_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137155: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_xslt_resolver_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137155: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_xslt_resolver_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137155: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_xslt_resolver_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137156: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_access_control’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137156: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_access_control’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137156: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_access_control’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137156: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_access_control’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137157: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137157: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137157: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137157: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_traverse_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137167: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_xslt_resolver_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137168: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_xslt_resolver_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137170: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_access_control’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137171: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_access_control’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137173: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137174: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__pyx_tp_clear_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137185: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_xslt_resolver_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137186: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_xslt_resolver_context’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137188: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_access_control’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137189: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_access_control’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137191: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:137192: error: ‘struct __pyx_obj_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_error_log’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘initetree’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139524: error: ‘tagMatches’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139527: error: ‘hasText’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139528: error: ‘hasTail’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139529: error: ‘textOf’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139530: error: ‘tailOf’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139531: error: ‘setNodeText’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139532: error: ‘setTailText’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139533: error: ‘attributeValue’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139534: error: ‘attributeValueFromNsName’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139537: error: ‘collectAttributes’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139540: error: ‘delAttributeFromNsName’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139541: error: ‘hasChild’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139542: error: ‘findChild’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139543: error: ‘findChildForwards’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139544: error: ‘findChildBackwards’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139545: error: ‘nextElement’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139546: error: ‘previousElement’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139551: error: ‘namespacedName’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139555: error: ‘findOrBuildNodeNsPrefix’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139604: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__Document’ has no member named ‘_findOrBuildNodeNs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139604: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_9_Document__findOrBuildNodeNs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139605: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__Document’ has no member named ‘_setNodeNs’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139630: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__BaseParser’ has no member named ‘_newParserCtxt’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139630: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11_BaseParser__newParserCtxt’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139631: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__BaseParser’ has no member named ‘_newPushParserCtxt’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139631: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11_BaseParser__newPushParserCtxt’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139632: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__BaseParser’ has no member named ‘_copy’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139633: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__BaseParser’ has no member named ‘_parseUnicodeDoc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139633: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11_BaseParser__parseUnicodeDoc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139634: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__BaseParser’ has no member named ‘_parseDoc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139634: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11_BaseParser__parseDoc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139635: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__BaseParser’ has no member named ‘_parseDocFromFile’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139635: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11_BaseParser__parseDocFromFile’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139636: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__BaseParser’ has no member named ‘_parseDocFromFilelike’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139636: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_11_BaseParser__parseDocFromFilelike’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139815: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree_ElementDepthFirstIterator’ has no member named ‘_nextNodeAnyTag’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139815: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_25ElementDepthFirstIterator__nextNodeAnyTag’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139816: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree_ElementDepthFirstIterator’ has no member named ‘_nextNodeMatchTag’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:139816: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_25ElementDepthFirstIterator__nextNodeMatchTag’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140011: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserContext’ has no member named ‘_handleParseResultDoc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140011: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_14_ParserContext__handleParseResultDoc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140045: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserContext’ has no member named ‘_handleParseResultDoc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140045: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_20_TargetParserContext__handleParseResultDoc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140106: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserDictionaryContext’ has no member named ‘_getThreadDict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140106: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_24_ParserDictionaryContext__getThreadDict’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140107: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserDictionaryContext’ has no member named ‘initThreadDictRef’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140108: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserDictionaryContext’ has no member named ‘initParserDict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140109: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserDictionaryContext’ has no member named ‘initXPathParserDict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140110: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserDictionaryContext’ has no member named ‘initDocDict’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140111: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserDictionaryContext’ has no member named ‘findImpliedContext’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140112: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserDictionaryContext’ has no member named ‘pushImpliedContextFromParser’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140113: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserDictionaryContext’ has no member named ‘pushImpliedContext’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140114: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__ParserDictionaryContext’ has no member named ‘popImpliedContext’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140128: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__FileReaderContext’ has no member named ‘_createParserInputBuffer’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140128: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_18_FileReaderContext__createParserInputBuffer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140129: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__FileReaderContext’ has no member named ‘_createParserInput’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140129: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_18_FileReaderContext__createParserInput’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140130: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__FileReaderContext’ has no member named ‘_readDtd’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140130: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_18_FileReaderContext__readDtd’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140131: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__FileReaderContext’ has no member named ‘_readDoc’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140131: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_18_FileReaderContext__readDoc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140132: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__FileReaderContext’ has no member named ‘copyToBuffer’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140236: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__FilelikeWriter’ has no member named ‘_createOutputBuffer’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140236: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_15_FilelikeWriter__createOutputBuffer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140237: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__FilelikeWriter’ has no member named ‘write’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140238: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree__FilelikeWriter’ has no member named ‘close’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140508: error: ‘struct __pyx_vtabstruct_4lxml_5etree_XSLT’ has no member named ‘_run_transform’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:140508: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_4XSLT__run_transform’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141405: error: ‘xmlParserVersion’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:141555: error: ‘LIBXML_VERSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142365: error: ‘__pyx_v_4lxml_5etree___DEFAULT_ENTITY_LOADER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142374: error: ‘__pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__local_resolver’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142383: error: ‘XML_PARSE_NOENT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142383: error: ‘XML_PARSE_NOCDATA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142383: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘struct PyMemberDef *’ and ‘struct PyMemberDef *’)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142383: error: ‘XML_PARSE_NONET’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142383: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘struct PyMemberDef *’ and ‘struct PyMemberDef *’)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142383: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘struct PyMemberDef *’ and ‘int’)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142643: error: ‘XML_PARSE_RECOVER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142643: error: ‘HTML_PARSE_NONET’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142643: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘struct PyMemberDef *’ and ‘struct PyMemberDef *’)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:142643: error: invalid operands to binary | (have ‘struct PyMemberDef *’ and ‘int’)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:143135: error